# Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [amt.replace is not a function]

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

```
var amt = cmp.find("amount").get("v.value"); 
amt = parseFloat(amt.replace(/.*\$/,'').replace(/[^.\d]/g,''));
```

i am getting

> Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [amt.replace is not a function]

in Lightning component controller

Comment: Can you put some more code of your controller js?

Comment: Is `amt` a string?